# Hints with implementing add(index, element) function in a LinkedList in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, junit, linked-list, addition

I'm currently trying to teach myself Data Structures through Allen Downey's Think Data Structures book and I'm on excersize 3 where I'm reimplementing methods to Java's LinkedList class. I'm working on a method that allows you to add an element to a specified index in the linkedlist. I have attemped two implementations which both fail the provided JUnit test. Thank you for the help and sorry if I'm missing something super obvious, it happens to me all the time. If possible, I would appreciate hints to the right direction rather than getting the answer itself.

I have tried

```
public void add(int index, E element) {
        Node newNode = new Node(element);
        Node node = getNode(index);
        newNode.next = node;
        node = getNode(index - 1);
        node.next = newNode;
    }
```

and

```
public void add(int index, E element) {
        Node newNode = new Node(element, getNode(index));
        getNode(index-1).next = newNode;
    }
```

which the JUnit test for both says Expected is <4> but was <3>
The java files I'm working with are in this repository: https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkDataStructures/tree/master/code/src/com/allendowney/thinkdast
Which the two specific files are MyLinkedList.java and MyLinkedListTest.java

Comment: How is the size calculated?

Comment: Size is set at 0 when the list is initialized and size++ is called whenever the add(element) *with no specified index* is called.

Comment: So what could be the reason that when an element is added on a specific index, the size is one too low? :)

Comment: When thinking about algorithms on custom data structures I usually like to imagine that I am a train worker on a railway system. Imagine yourself in terms of being able to drive from station to station and set the switches to connect the stations in a particular order. What would you tell someone who wants to add an element (station) to a specific index. Which switches would he have to set to achieve the new order. Doing it graphically can help too.

Comment: I've reworked the code to this, I'm still not passing the JUnit test, but I feel like I'm closer.
``` public void add(int index, E element) {
  if (index == 0) {
   Node node = head;
   Node newNode = new Node(element, node);
   size++;
  }
  else {
   Node node = head;
   for (int i=0; i<index - 1; i++) {
    node = node.next;
   }
   Node newNode = new Node(element, node.next);
   node.next = newNode;
   size++;
  }
 }```

Comment: I got it working! I had to let the program know what the new head was going to be in the scenario that the new element added was at the front of the list. Thank you all for the help!